# In differentiating $n\ln{p}+(\sum y-n)\ln(1-p)$ with respect to $p$ to get $\frac{n}{p}-(\sum y-n)\frac{1}{1-p}$, why does the "$+$" change to "$-$"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hi have the following maximum likelihood estimation for p.

$$\ln{L(B)} = n \ln{p} + (\sum y-n) \ln(1-p)$$

When it is differentiated the result is:

$$\frac{n}{p} -(\sum y-n)\frac{1}{1-p}$$

I'm wondering why does the plus in "$n \ln p + (\sum y-n)$" turn to a minus?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have $\ln(1-p)' = \ln'(1-p)(1-p)' = -\frac{1}{1-p}$. To be more exact,you have $\frac{d}{dp}[n\ln(p) + (\sum y-n)\ln(1-p)] = \frac{n}{p} + (\sum y-n)(-\frac{1}{1-p}) = \frac{n}{p} - (\sum y-n)/(1-p)$. More generally $f(g(x))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)$. Here, $f(x) = \ln(x)$ and $g(x) = 1-x$, so $f(g(p))' = f'(g(p))g'(p) = \frac{1}{1-p}(-1)$.

Comment: Thank you  for your explanation